# css overflow with elements moved outside div, elements disappear

Tags: overflow, css-position

I have a form in a div where I brought submit buttons out of the div to another part of the screen.  This works nicely.  However, I want to lock that div down to a specific size and relative position and use overflow:auto so when it grows too big (the form has elements that are unhidden with checkboxes) the entire screen doesn't scroll, just the div.  The problem is, as soon as I add the overflow style, the submit boxes I moved off the div are hidden.  I assume this is because with overflow all elements are locked into that div and scroll bars allow you to access them, but in this case the elements are moved left:-500px and it doesn't even give me a scroll bar to scroll left to see them.  Basic code follows:

```
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2">
  <form>
   <input type="submit" class="sub1" />
  </form>
 </div>
</div>`
```

CSS would be:

```
div.div1 {
 position:relative;
 width:1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
div.div2 {
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 position:absolute;
 top:125px;
 left:500px;
}
input[type=submit].sub1 {
 position:absolute;
 left: -500px;
}
```

So this works, but as soon as I change the div2 css to:

```
div.div2 {
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 position:absolute;
 top:125px;
 left:500px;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

The submit button disappears.

My question: is there any way to get the scrollbar and keep the div2 container to 500px high without losing the elements outside the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can move `div2` within the `form` and leave the submit button outside of `div2`. That way, the submit button will always be visible and `div2` can have overflow.

```
<div class="div1">
  <form>
    <div class="div2">
      <!-- form fields go here -->
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="sub1" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: You'll likely need to adjust styles on the button, but I'm not entirely sure about your end goal.

Comment: I was able to make that work.. Thanks for the idea!  I was able to just move my container div for the form inside the form then duplicate that container as a new class and enclose just the submit buttons in the new div container.  That kept the buttons where I already had them without having to recalculate all the positioning and I applied the overflow to the original div and got what I needed.  Thanks!